# Reorder or reduce console output

Tags: warnings

After running pdftexify, I get a long console output of several hundred lines. Hidden within this output, there are a few bad boxes and sometimes a warning. Is there some way to reduce the output such that only the bad boxes and warnings are shown? Or, alternatively, is it possible to reprint the parts with bad boxes and warnings at the end of the output? Such that I can spot and address the presented issues easily.

Comment: `texloganalyser -o <filename>` (from a command shell) should print on the screen the information about overfull hboxes.

Comment: I didn't get this to work just yet. But should I conclude from your comment, that this cannot be automated. I use WinEdt 7.0 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class option `draft` to mark all over- or underfull boxes with an black box on the right side in your pdf.

With Ctrl+E in WinEDT you can follow the errors and warnings (starting with the first one), so no need to have a separate second log.

You have to install an perl interpreter to run `texloganalyser`, for example you can try cygwin.  Then you need a batch file, first starting texloganalyser in cygwin, then calling `pdflatex`. Now use in WinEDT `Options` --> `execution Modes` an generate there a new executor for your batch file. Now WinEDT should be able to run your batch ...