# Silence file inclusion messages?

Tags: external-files

The question seems so natural, that I would have expected it to be well researched. But, I could not find any resources.

In compiling my source, I get notified on 249 file inclusions. This clutter makes it difficult to see more urgent problems. Any way of silencing these messages?

Comment: No; the notification of the files opened for `\input` is hard coded in TeX and can't be “silenced”. You may want to try filtering the `.log` file with `texloganalyser`. For instance, `texloganalyser -o <file>` shows only the overfull box messages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was answered in the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reorder or reduce console output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130153/reorder-or-reduce-console-output)